# Spring output console dissapeared after removing logback dependency

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, logback

I am trying to use log4j2 as logger, for that i have included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and used

```
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

in every dependency that used logback due to conflict, however after doing this, the spring upon running prints only its Logo and nothing.

DO i need to configure somehow spring for log4j2 or how to solve this?

Comment: Have you configured loggers and appenders in a log4j properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes offcourse. You need to create log4j2.xml in src/main/resources path.
In that Xml file you need to configure your application logging level in ConsoleAppender.

Please add this xml configuration in log4j2.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

     <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%level] [%logger{36}] - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"></AppenderRef>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```